# My AWS EC2 has stopped receiving POST data from Beanstalk worker environments

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to figure out a problem which has surfaced in our systems today in regards to communication between an AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker environment (let us call this the **"worker"**) with a standalone EC2 instance (let us call this instance **"EC2"**). The *worker* sends out two POST requests using stream_context_create. The first is sent to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk web-server environment (let us call this environment the **"web-server"**) and the second is sent to *EC2* which is supposed to receive, process the request and send a response.

These two requests were being sent, received, processed and responded to correctly without any problems up until today. But then this afternoon I realised the second request from the *worker* to *EC2* had stopped working. The *EC2* environment was receiving the request, but the POST data was empty.

I have other AWS Elastic Beanstalk web-server environments (let us call them **"other web servers"**) which are also communicating with *EC2* in the same fashion as the *worker* (exactly the same code structure) and *EC2* correctly receives the POST data from them. So I'm lost as to why the request data from the *worker* is being received empty by *EC2*.

Here is the code structure which is used to send the request from the *worker* to *EC2*. The structure is the same across all requests that I send.

```
    $url = 'https://ec2-99-99-999-999.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/path';

    $data = array(
        'key' => 'key_value',
        'document' => 'html_code_string'
    );

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => [
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Cv-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
            ],
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
        'ssl'=>array(
            'verify_peer'=>false,
            'verify_peer_name'=>false
        )
    ));

    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

On *EC2*, I'm using the **$_POST** array to access the request data, but it is empty when the request is sent from the *worker*. This same array holds the request data when the request is sent from the *other web servers*.

When the same codebase is used to send a request from the *worker* to the *web-server*, the *web-server* is receiving the data as expected. And when a request is sent from the *other web-servers* to *EC2*, it is receiving the request data as expected as well.

So it seems there's an issue when an AWS Worker environment is trying to send a post request to an AWS EC2 instance. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Prathamesh.

Comment: Hey everyone, an update. I tried sending the request using Postman, and I found that if I use the form-data setting, the request works as expected as the POST data is received. Another interesting thing I found was that when I remove the html_string from the request data and keep the content type as x-www-form-urlencoded, the remaining request data is received. So it seems sending the html string is messing up the entire request. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hey everyone, have still been trying to work this out .. I have been trying different combinations of the systems and they all seem to be working in my local environment even with the html string in the request body. I tried a relatively smaller html string in the request body and it also worked on the EC2 instance which is causing the problem. So is it to do with the size of the request data variable? The whole request is 75702 bytes (~0.7MB) which falls way under the allowed 8MB my php.ini is currently set to.

Answer (score 0):

I've got my systems working for now. I had updated the SSL certificates for the various instances we run our services (not the EC2 instance which was not receiving the request correctly) nor the worker environment as they work off AWS domains. But for some reason, when I uploaded some debug code into the EC2 instance as a new codebase, everything suddently just started working again.

I have no idea how the issue first started and why after just updating the codebase with just some extra debug lines to find where the problem was occurring that everything started working again.

It sounds like the EC2 instance just needed a refresh but I haven't actually refreshed the EC2 instance. This is just a guess as I have exhausted all possible explanations in the domain of knowledge I possess which apparently isn't enough to explain this.

Going forward I'll keep the strategy of updating the codebase in mind but if you guys feel anything is worth looking please let me know.

Thanks and regards,

Prathamesh.